# IIS 7 my site works using localhost but using 127.0.0.1 or my IP 192.168.1.66 fails

Tags: iis, iis-7, localhost

My question title basically says it all.  I was reading some other questions that are similar to this, but I think I need some help on trouble shooting it.  Can't seem to figure it out.

Using IIS 7, my site works fine using localhost but when I try to get to it from either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.66, the browser can't find the site.  The browser gives up and redirects me to www.127.0.0.1, which I think is a fall-back attempt at resolving the url.

I've tried this in IE, and Firefox.  Same behaviours.  Interestingly, Chrome takes a lot longer to decide that the site isn't available, and eventually times out.

First question will be about bindings.  The site setting is:

- type: http
- hostname: (blank)
- port: 8080
- IP Address: *

Any ideas on the first place to look?

Comment: You are typing the port number in URL, right?

Comment: yes, i've got the port number in there.